# python - extract text from microsoft word

Tags: python, ms-word

I'm trying to extract text in specific parts of an MS word document ([link](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp//Specs/archive/36_series/36.331/36331-f80.zip)) - sample below. Essentially I need to write all text with the tags `-- ASN1START` and `-- ASN1STOP` to a file excluding the aforementioned tags.

sample text

```
-- ASN1START

CounterCheck ::=            SEQUENCE {
    rrc-TransactionIdentifier           RRC-TransactionIdentifier,
    criticalExtensions                  CHOICE {
        c1                                  CHOICE {
            counterCheck-r8                     CounterCheck-r8-IEs,
            spare3 NULL, spare2 NULL, spare1 NULL
        },
        criticalExtensionsFuture            SEQUENCE {}
    }
}

CounterCheck-r8-IEs ::= SEQUENCE {
    drb-CountMSB-InfoList               DRB-CountMSB-InfoList,
    nonCriticalExtension                CounterCheck-v8a0-IEs               OPTIONAL
}

CounterCheck-v8a0-IEs ::= SEQUENCE {
    lateNonCriticalExtension            OCTET STRING                        OPTIONAL,
    nonCriticalExtension                CounterCheck-v1530-IEs              OPTIONAL
}

CounterCheck-v1530-IEs ::= SEQUENCE {
    drb-CountMSB-InfoListExt-r15        DRB-CountMSB-InfoListExt-r15        OPTIONAL,   -- Need ON
    nonCriticalExtension                SEQUENCE {}                         OPTIONAL
}

DRB-CountMSB-InfoList ::=       SEQUENCE (SIZE (1..maxDRB)) OF DRB-CountMSB-Info

DRB-CountMSB-InfoListExt-r15 ::=    SEQUENCE (SIZE (1..maxDRBExt-r15)) OF DRB-CountMSB-Info

DRB-CountMSB-Info ::=   SEQUENCE {
    drb-Identity                    DRB-Identity,
    countMSB-Uplink                 INTEGER(0..33554431),
    countMSB-Downlink               INTEGER(0..33554431)
}

-- ASN1STOP
```

I have tried using `docx`.

```
from docx import *
import re
import json

fileName = './data/36331-f80.docx'
document = Document(fileName)

startText = re.compile(r'-- ASN1START')

for para in document.paragraphs:
    # look for each paragraph
    text = para.text
    print(text)
    # if startText.match(para.text):
    #     print(text)
```

It seems every line here with the tags mentioned above is a paragraph. I need help with extracting just the text within the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try first reading all document/paragraph text into a single string, and then using `re.findall` to find all matching text in between the target tags:

```
text = ""
for para in document.paragraphs:
    text += para.text + "\n"

matches = re.findall(r'-- ASN1START\s*(.*?)\s*-- ASN1STOP', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Note that we use DOT ALL mode with the regex to ensure that `.*` can match content in between the tags which occurs across newlines.

Comment: with `text.append(para.text)` gets error: `Instance of 'str' has no 'append' memberpylint(no-member)`

Comment: also how do we write these matches to a file ? Observe that in print(matches) there are many escape characters present like - `'UERadioPagingInformation-NB ::= SEQUENCE {\tcriticalExtensions\t\t\t\t\tCHOICE {\t\tc1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCHOICE{\t\t\tueRadioPagingInformation-r13\t\t\tUERadioPagingInformation-NB-IEs,`

Comment: This is most likely just what Python's interpreter is showing you.  If written to a text file, then the `\t` e.g. would appear as tabs.

Comment: One issue I'm facing is that the line breaks in the original text are not captured in the output, rather text within each tag is captured as a single line and that is causing some syntax error. I've update the sample text to reflect this issue. The part of each line starting with `-- ` is a comment. Is there a way to preserve the line breaks as in the original text ?

Comment: Yes, do a find all on `-- ASN1START(.*?)-- ASN1STOP`

Comment: I don't think that helped. For the example text in OP `DRB-CountMSB-InfoListExt-r15  OPTIONAL, -- Need ON nonCriticalExtension    SEQUENCE {}` is coming in a single line where as it is expected that the part after `-- Need ON` to be on the next line

Comment: got this working with adding a new line as `text += para.text + "\n"` - updated the answer.